# How to install Anbox in Parrot OS?

Tags: python, android, linux, parrot-os

Hello i need to install Anbox for running some of android apps in my parrot machine,i tried install the anbox by the documentation provide by them , For installing the Kernel Modules i need to add ppa repo it give exception

### sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support

*gives exception*

#### aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Parrot/n/a

**Can you help me to install the anbox in my parrot machine**

Answer (score 1):

Parrot OS does not take `add-apt-repository` command.

Try adding manually in the sources file instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo snap install --devmode --edge anbox
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, consider explain *why* and *how* for the benefit of OP and future readers